# magento 2.3 redirect all product urls without category path to urls with category path

Tags: magento2.3, product-urls, redirect-url

I want to redirect all product URLs without a category path to their category path URLs for SEO purposes.

> Example - Redirect mywebsite.com/product-name.html to
>   mywebsite.com/category1/sub-category/product-name.html.

I am thinking to override the observer on the event when a url is hit in magento. 
How to find that event?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your catalog configuration.

> Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs  to **NO**
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Answer (score 0):

Override product controller in Vendor/Module/Product/View.php with below code -

namespace [Vendor_Name][Module_Name]\Controller\Product;
  use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
  class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
  {

public function execute($coreRoute = null) {

```
$productid = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$initialUrl =$urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();

  if($productid){
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');


    $product = $productRepository->getById($productid);
    $productUrlKey = $product->getUrlKey();

    $baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB,true); 

    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $categories = $categoryCollection->create()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds);

       foreach ($categories as $category){
            $categoryNames[] = $category->getUrlKey();
         }

      if(strpos($initialUrl,$categoryNames[0])===false){       
        if (array_key_exists(1,$categoryNames)) {
            $productNewPath = $baseurl.$categoryNames[1].'/'.$categoryNames[0].'/'.$productUrlKey.'.'.'html';
          }        
        else{
           $productNewPath = $baseurl.$categoryNames[0].'/'.$productUrlKey.'.'.'html';
         }

            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($productNewPath);
              return $resultRedirect;

        }

$params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$params->setCategoryId($categoryIds);
$page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->viewHelper->prepareAndRender($page, $productid, $this, $params);
return $page;


 }
```

}
}